# Sudo with php to change file owner

Tags: php, sudo

I am running a php script and I want at runtime to be able to change a file owner to Linux user from www-data then after some house keeping change it back.

I am running the following command

```
$cmd = "sudo chown  www-data ".$path;
shell_exec($cmd);
```

where $path is a full path

i have added the following to my sudoers file with sudo visudo

```
www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: /fullpath/to/phpfile.php
```

but upon cheching my error logs I still get

```
^Msudo:: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

what could be the problem guys?
thanks

Comment: Whenver you type sudo you need to provide the password for sudo   and how are you providing password

Comment: YOU ABSOLUTELY SHOULD NOT DO THAT!  Any PHP script that can run as root, even on a temporary basis, is a massive security risk.  If you need a script to do some housekeeping then have it running as a cron job, then you can make the script run as whatever user you need it to run as without exposing it publicly.

Comment: Its not exactly house keeping at runtime i need to change the ownership of the file so that mp4box can write files to that directory

Comment: which user runs mp4box ?

Comment: mp4box is run by www-data using shell_exec()

Answer (score 3):

**Warning** Using `sudo` in a php script is a terrible idea, as it has huge security implications.

### 1. Clean and secure solution

> i need to change the ownership of the file so that mp4box can write files to that directory

Let's say your directory is /srv/directory. You need to create a group that contains the `www-data` user and any user that will write to the directory (let's say there is only one user: `tony`).

```
groupadd mygroup
usermod -a -G mygroup www-data,tony
```

then change the directory ownership and permissions accordingly.

```
chown -R /srv/directory www-data:mygroup
chmod -R /srv/directory 770
```

but that is configuration/installation part and such command should not be run at runtime as it might require root access. It would allow any php script to do anything on the computer. **this should be run when you install and configure the environement** your script will run on.

#### not dev-ops note :

@my sysadmin: if you read this, please don't kill me.

You shouldn't care about user permissions at runtime as it is sysadmin's job to make the system secure and ensure your code can run on it. Because you don't care about that, there should not be any sudo in your code.
However, **there is not a single sysadmin on earth that would grant root access to the `www-data` user** (maybe there are, but they get fired quickly).

#### more dev-ops note :

If you are a kind person that don't want to be hated by his co-workers and/or user. You should :

- document the needs of write access to directory X or Y.
- Maybe create an install script that will do the configuration job as root just once.
- Or maybe create a Docker container, or a virtual machine that is preconfigured to run your code.

### 2. tldr; I-don't-care-about-security solution

take a look at [this unix stack exchange post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43135/allowing-a-user-to-use-sudo-without-a-password)

Comment: Problem is that the file i am trying to change permissions for is created bu php at runtime so i dont have the option of mannualy changing the user or group that ia why i am trying to run this by script

Comment: if it does not have the needed rights, it means it has not been created by php. But once again, it is not a programmation problem, it's an admin-one.

Comment: what is the owner/group of the file ? if that's root, you need to configure the daemon that produce that file to write with another owner/group. If that's another unprivileged group, you just need to add www-data to that group once (`sudo usermod -a -G mygroup www-data`), and you are done.

Comment: it is created by php when i chown it to root user mp4box writes comfortably

Comment: Please, tell what is the owner of the file, what user runs MP4Box, where does MP4Box saves its output and finally what are the owner/group of that output.

Comment: it is created by php when i chown it to root user from the command line mp4box writes comfortably

Comment: if i run mp4box from php shell_exec isnt it www-data running when i run it from the command line i run it as ubuntu

Comment: I'm fed up with tis, I give up.

Comment: n00dl3 Mp4box saves (well tries to) its output to a file created at runtime by php using the mkdir command and the output is owned by root i gues that is why it is not able to save because if i run the mp4box command from the terminal with sudo or i chown the file to root from the terminal and run the command without sudo then the saves are done without a problem so it is a permissions error